# Module 'httpMock' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, jasmine, protractor

This is error message on a protractor test use protractor http mock:

> JavascriptError: javascript error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'httpMock'
>   is not available! You eit her misspelled the module name or forgot to
>   load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the
>   dependencies as the second argument.

conf.js:

```
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
    // Selenium server
  SeleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
    //baseUrl: 'http://develop.garbo.livebranches.com/sv-SE/',
    //Framework to use. Jasmine 2 is recommended.
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    //frameworks: ['mocha', 'jasmine'],

    // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
    // protractor is called.
    //specs: ['testmain.js','testlogin.js'],
    //specs: ['testmain.js','testteaPartyList.js','testpositionSearchIndex.js','testpositionList.js'],
    specs: ['testlogin.js'],

    //Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 250000
  },
  mocks: {
        dir: '../node_modules/protractor-http-mock',
        //dir: 'mocks',
        default: []
    },
  //=====login begin =====
 onPrepare: function() {
    require("protractor-http-mock").config = {
    rootDirectory: '../node_modules/protractor-http-mock/lib',
    //rootDirectory: __dirname,

    protractorConfig: "conf.js",  // name of the config here
    };

  }

  //=====login end========


};
```

testlogin.js

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {

    //browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  it('should login', function() {
    var mock = require('protractor-http-mock');
    var todoList;

    beforeEach(function() {

        var url ='http://dev.etest.com:285/Actor/tbUsers/LoginAndGet';

        var req = {Mobile:'14500000006',Password:'123456'};

        var rep = {UserId:164,AccountId:328,Token:'328:dc91d536ab424aa0b8d7f1ecaf64c55b',Id:328};

        mock([{
        request: {
          path: url,
          method: 'POST',
          data:req,
        },
        response: {
          data: rep,
        }
        }]);
    });
    afterEach(function() {
        mock.teardown();
    });

    browser.get('http://localhost:2024/daNiuJob/www/ionicWeb/index.html#/login');

    console.log('mock='+mock);

    element(by.model('data.userName')).sendKeys('14500000006');
    element(by.model('data.password')).sendKeys('123456');
    var btnlogin = element(by.id('Regist')).element(by.tagName('a'));   

    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('userlogin');

        browser.getTitle().then(function(text){

        console.log('title='+text);
    });

    //cause mock error
    expect(mock.requestsMade()).toEqual([
        { url : 'http://dev.etest.com:285/Actor/tbUsers/LoginAndGet', method : 'GET' },
    ]);

    btnlogin.click();


    browser.sleep(8000);

    });


});
```

Why can't find `httpMock`, thank!

note:

```
C:\Users\HQ-XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\protractor-http-mock
```

This is path of 'protractor-http-mock'

Comment: Error is because protractor is not able to find your httpMock module in the specified path. If your node_modules directory is relative to your project directory and inside it then use `rootDirectory: './node_modules/protractor-http-mock/lib',`. Or let me know how the folder structure looks like to help you with that.

Comment: C:\Users\HQ-XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\protractor-http-mock

This is path of 'protractor-http-mock'

Comment: C:\Users\HQ-XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example\conf.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be giving the path of the http-mock module folder and not lib folder inside it. Change your rootDirectory path of `protractor-http-mock` inside `onPrepare()` function to -

```
rootDirectory: 'C:\Users\HQ-XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\protrac‌​tor-http-mock ',
```

If at all you need to provide a relative path then change it as below -

```
rootDirectory: '..\node_modules\protrac‌​tor-http-mock ',
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and it was related to the page reloading at the beginning of every spec.

This was caused by a faulty config of html5mode and the browser.get so it did a redirect at the beginning from foo.bar/ to foo.bar/#/ which unloads all injected protractor code.